# Why do dashes mess up regex search?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have 150 files each with a header similar to this one

```
---
layout: page
title:  "WE07S-AWE"
date:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600
---

Lots of text here...
```

where I would like to extract the title `WE07S-AWE` and everything after the second line of dashes.

However the dashes messes up the search somehow.

```
$ ruby -pe 's/---.*title:  "(.*?)".*---(.*)/m' test
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '.'
s/---.*title:  "(.*?)".*---(.*)/m
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '.'
s/---.*title:  "(.*?)".*---(.*)/m
```

## Question

Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: even with those fixes, I get the same error... Updated OP with your version

Comment: The header is obviously YAML, why not use a YAML parser to parse it instead of writing your own?

Comment: The syntax error is caused by the stray `s` before the `/` which makes it *not* a regex literal but actually "`s` divided something", and that "something" is then syntactically not legal. Ruby is expecting something like `s/---1` which *would* be legal and is equivalent to `s./(1.-@().-@().-@())`, i.e. "`s` divided by minus-minus-minus one".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```rb
ruby -0777 -pe 'sub(/---.*title:\s*"(.*?)".*---(.*)/m, "\\1 \\2")' test
ruby -0777 -ne 'print $1 + $2 if /---.*title:\s*"(.*?)".*---(.*)/m' test
```

**Details**

- `-0777` will slurp the file into a single string
- `m` modifier makes `.` match line break chars, too, that it does not match by default
- Instead of a single literal space between `title:` and `"`, a `\s*` is used to match zero or more whitespaces
- `sub` will replace the match with the contents of Group 1 + Group 2, `\1 \2`.
- `-n` assumes 'while gets(); ... end' loop around your script
- `print $1 + $2 if /---.*title:\s*"(.*?)".*---(.*)/m` will print Group 1 + Group 2 value if regex matches.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should avoid the `.*` pattern when possible. Not only could it be a high performance risk, it often doesn't really describe what you're looking for.

For example, if your `title` never escapes the `"` character, a better approach might be:

```
 /title:[\s]+"([^"]+)".*---(.*)/m
```

The rest of the details are better [answered by Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627249/4025095) (who's answer I will upvote).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `str = File.read(<filename>)`, where

```
str = <<~BITTER_END
---
layout: page
title:  "WE07S-AWE"
date:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600
---
Humpty Dumpty sat
on a wall
---
layout: page
title:  "WE08RS-WEA"
date:  2018-10-22 07:31:26.000000000 -0600
---
Little Miss
Muffet sat on
her tuffet
---
layout: page
title:  "AR91G-HUH"
date:  2017-03-13 01:30:26.000000000 -0800
---
Three blind mice
See how they run
BITTER_END
```

Rather than using a single regular expression you may wish perform a sequence of operations, both to improve readability and facilitate testing. I will use two regular expressions:

```
r1 = /^---\r?\n/
r2 = /^title: +"([^"]+)/
```

`r1` reads, "match a line comprised of three hyphens". `^` is the beginning-of-line anchor and `\r?\n` is the line terminator (which optionally includes the *carriage return* character `\r` in case the file was created using Windows).

`r2` reads "match 'title:' at the beginning of a line followed by one or more spaces (`+`), a double-quote, followed by one or more characters other than a double-quote (as many as possible). `[^"]` is a *character class* that matches any character other than `"`.

We may then write:

```
str.split(r1).
    drop(1).
    each_slice(2).
    with_object({}) { |(header,body),h| h[header[r2,1]] = body }
  #=> {"WE07S-AWE"=>"Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n",
  #    "WE08RS-WEA"=>"Little Miss\nMuffet sat on\nher tuffet\n",
  #    "AR91G-HUH"=>"Three blind mice\nSee how they run\n"}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = str.split(r1)
  #=> ["",
  #    "layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE07S-AWE\"\ndate:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600\n",
  #    "Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n",
  #    "layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE08RS-WEA\"\ndate:  2018-10-22 07:31:26.000000000 -0600\n",
  #    "Little Miss\nMuffet sat on\nher tuffet\n",
  #    "layout: page\ntitle:  \"AR91G-HUH\"\ndate:  2017-03-13 01:30:26.000000000 -0800\n",
  #    "Three blind mice\nSee how they run\n"] 
b = a.drop(1)
  #=> ["layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE07S-AWE\"\ndate:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600\n",
  #   ...
  #    "Three blind mice\nSee how they run\n"] 
c = b.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE07S-AWE\"\ndate:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600\n",..., "Three blind mice\nSee how they run\n"]:each_slice(2)>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by the enumerator `c` and passed to `with_object` by converting it to an array.

```
c.to_a
  #=> [["layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE07S-AWE\"\ndate:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600\n",
  #     "Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n"],
  #    ["layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE08RS-WEA\"\ndate:  2018-10-22 07:31:26.000000000 -0600\n",
  #     "Little Miss\nMuffet sat on\nher tuffet\n"],
  #    ["layout: page\ntitle:  \"AR91G-HUH\"\ndate:  2017-03-13 01:30:26.000000000 -0800\n",
  #     "Three blind mice\nSee how they run\n"]]
```

Continuing,

```
d = c.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["layout:...]:each_slice(2)>:each_with_object({"\"WE07S-AWE"=>"Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n"})>
```

`d` may be thought of as a *compound enumerator* though Ruby has no such concept. Continuing,

```
(header,body),h = d.next
  #=> [["layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE07S-AWE\"\ndate:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600\n",
  #      "Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n"],
  #    {}]
```

Ruby uses [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to break `d.next` into three objects which respectively become values of the three block variables `header`, `body` and `h`. Let's examine those values.

```
header
  #=> "layout: page\ntitle:  \"WE07S-AWE\"\ndate:  2018-10-21 01:31:26.000000000 -0600\n" 
body
  #=> "Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n" 
h #=> {}
```

This is the initial value of `h`. It will be built in the course of the calculations. Now examine the block calculation.

```
s = header[r2,1]
  #=> "WE07S-AWE"
h[s] = body
  #=> "Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n"
```

so now

```
h #=> {"WE07S-AWE"=>"Humpty Dumpty sat\non a wall\n"}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

See [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split), [Array#drop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-drop), [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object).